# Java If-Else Loops

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to make this program work. It checks if a string of text entered by the user is equal to one of three. Here is my code:

```
boolean acceptableanswer;
if(choice == choice1){
    acceptableanswer=true;
    return choice1;
}else if(choice == choice2){
    acceptableanswer=true;
    return choice2;
}else if(choice == choice3){
    acceptableanswer=true;
    return choice3;
}else{
    acceptableanswer=false;
    return null;
}
```

The problem is, it automatically goes to "null".

Comment: Please correct the subject of question : if..else if..else is not a loop. A loop is something which keeps on going till its condition is true e.g. while, for, do..while,  whereas an if block is executed just once when a condition is true.

Comment: I am a newbie to programming. Thanks. Can you answer the question? How do you change the title?

Comment: if(choice.equals(choice1)){...} use .equals instead of == as mentioned by jhobbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string equality you have to use `string1.equals(string2)`.